# Can we control how AWS Glue manages EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-emr

I have a use case where I need to check if a Glue Job is already running and if yes, for the new glue job reuse the same EMR cluster.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue is fully serverless, so there is no infrastructure to manage. Also, we do not know whether Glue run's EMR or some other cluster in the backend. Therefore, it is not possible to re-use the same cluster for the new Glue Job.  Please refer to this official [FAQ page](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/faqs/).